# XCode 5.1 crashes when I drag-drop one project into another project's tree

Tags: xcode, linker, crash, target

I've created a new "single view" iOS universal app.

I want to link theamazingaudioengine

I'm on step 2 here: http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/_getting-_started.html

> "Drag TheAmazingAudioEngine.xcodeproj from that folder into your
>   project's navigation tree in Xcode. It'll be added as a sub-project."

But instead, I'm trying to place it alongside:

[image]

To my mind it makes more sense that the project should be next to each other.

However, I can't include the .a as a target dependency.  I can't drag drop it. And if I click the +, there is no possibility to include it.

So maybe I am wrong, and I have to do exactly as the instruction says?

So I try to drag-drop "TheAmazingAudioEngine" into the Ultra project-tree, between "Ultra" project and "Ultra" folder.

This crashes Xcode.

It is repeatable.

Should I file a bug, and am I wrong to to place the projects side-by-side?

Answer (score 1):

It crashes for me too if I drag and drop.

Found that by using the `Add files to "my project"` setting it will work.

When you choose the Add files option, navigate and ONLY add the `theamazingaudioengine.xcodeproj` file. It will automatically add the whole project. Now you will be able to link.

Comment: But then TAAE is nested within MyProject, right? I can do that by drag dropping from Finder into MyProject's tree in XCode. I just can't get them working alongside one another.

Comment: OH, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. You can put them side by side. Then in your app target's Build Phases, go to Link Binaries and Frameworks. You should then see the .lib file and you can add it to your other project. You may find that you need to expose the headers though. A big reason people put projects in as sub projects is for the headers to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Version 5.1.1.  The update was released on April 10.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12